# cannot retrieve json data from express server?

Tags: javascript, express, server

I have created my first simple server using **express** but i can not retrieve json data from a **data.json** file:

This is the code of the server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/data', (req, res) => res.send('data.json'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

the **server.js** file is in the same level with **data folder** which contains **data.json** file from where i want to retrieve data

The server works ok but i get an error message `Cannot GET /`

What is wrong in my code??

Comment: try in your browser http://localhost:5000/data . you are forgetting the /data

Comment: besides, when you try the above link, you will only get the string "data.json" not the file, you're sending a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with the informations you provide us, there are 2 main errors:

`app.get('/data', (req, res) => res.send('data.json'))`

need to be replaced with:

`app.get('/data', (req, res) => res.sendFile('data/data.json'))`

because the data.json is in **data** folder and not at the same level as **server.js**

The second error is with the route. You `Cannot GET /` cause the only route you set is `/data` so you can perform a get request only from `localhost:5000/data`.

Tell me if there is something you want to understand more. https://expressjs.com/it/guide/routing.html

Comment: `/data` as the first param is not the folder you want to look for... is simply the path you need to write in your browser to retrieve data you define in res.send.

Comment: You can get your data from `localhost:5000/hello`

Comment: Thank you this is helpful, yes i know now why my code is wrong but i need to retrieve data from inside data.json instead now i get this messgae 'data/data.json'

Comment: Yes, my second comment was wrong, as https://stackoverflow.com/users/8434189/mahmouddafer wrote you need to use **res.sendFile** method instead **res.send**

Comment: Thank you, everything is ok now!!